# UIkit styling into CKEditor

Tags: ckeditor, getuikit

I would like my CKEditor text area to be styled based on the UIkit framework in order to have a direct overview of the display without having to click on proview.
I have already added the css in the config.js using

```
/* uikit.css */
    config.contentsCss = '/css/uikit.min.css';
```

However, UIkit also need its JS file to properly dynamic content such as tab or accordion for example.

How can I add the uikit.js into CKEditor?

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following in the config.js, it works as expect:

```
 CKEDITOR.on('instanceReady', function(ev) {
    var uikitScript = document.createElement('script');

    uikitScript.src = 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uikit@3.3.7/dist/js/uikit.min.js';


    var editorHead = ev.editor.document.$.head;
    editorHead.appendChild(uikitScript);   
});
```